# Nodejs - Wrong usage of promises

Tags: node.js, sql-server, asynchronous, promise

I have the following async method:

```
alreadyLoaded: async function (id) {
        const pool = await poolPromise;
        return pool.request()
                        .input('idParameter', id)
                        .query('SELECT count(*) AS value FROM dbo.partidos WHERE id=@idParameter')
                        .then(result => {
                            console.log(result.recordset[0].value)
                            result.recordset[0].value > 0
                        }).catch(function(err) {
                            console.log(err.message);
                        });
```

Invoked in another one:

```
processMatches: function(payload) {
    payload.matches.forEach(p => {

      if(partidosRepository.alreadyLoaded(p.id))
      {
        console.log("El partido ya fue cargado.");

        return;
      }
```

The `alreadyLoaded` method checks if some record is already inserted on database, and it's invoked inside another method to validate. The problem here is that the `processMatches` method continues processing records before the `alreadyLoaded` finishs with the current one.

I'm having a wrong manage of promises here, Can anyone help me solve this out?

Here's the database connection:

```
const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
                .connect()
                .then(pool => {
                    console.log('Connected to localhost '+ config.database +' database');
                    return pool;
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('Database connection failed. Error: ', err));
module.exports = {
    sql, poolPromise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build your if statement like this

```
if(await partidosRepository.alreadyLoaded(p.id))
```

also keep in mind you are not returning boolean value here

```
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err.message);
});
```